# Ruby replace if block with guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a service object which creates the CSV file from assigned data. The call method is pretty simple:

```
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def call
    CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ';') do |csv|
      csv << csv_headers

      data.uniq.each do |contract|
        next if contract.transient

        payment_details = [
          next_payment_date(contract),
          I18n.t("contracts.interval_options.#{contract.recurring_transaction_interval&.name}"),
        ]
        csv << payment_details
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def next_payment_date(contract)
    if contract.upcoming_installment.nil?
      I18n.t('tables.headers.no_next_payment_date')
    else
      contract.upcoming_installment.transaction_date.to_s
    end
  end
```

It works well but I don't think `next_payment_date` is really fancy if block, I'm wondering is it possible to replace it with some guard instead?

Because of rubocop I cannot use:

```
contract.upcoming_installment.nil? ? I18n.t('tables.headers.no_next_payment_date') : contract.upcoming_installment.transaction_date.to_s
```

Comment: What you're calling a "guard" is actually a ternary condition and Rubucop is right to slap you on the fingers as that code is way to long for a ternary condition.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the method looks fine as it is. Having better readability is a profitable trade-off for increasing LOCs or introducing methods. That said, there are ways where you can make it an one liner if you really fancy.

```
contract.upcoming_installment&.transaction_date || I18n.t('tables.headers.no_next_payment_date')
```

Ruby's safe navigation `&.` will return nil if `upcoming_installment` is nil which should fallback to the `I18n`.

Comment: The need for `&.transaction_date` here is really just due to a Law of Demeter violation. This should really be refactored by defining a method on contract.